# Can SelectOneMenu tag in ICEfaces be editable?

Tags: jsf, icefaces, ajax4jsf

I am creating a drop down list in datatable using ICEfaces now, I would like that this drop down list can either retrieve data from database, or manually entered data by user at the same time. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you mixing ICEfaces with RichFaces? Ajax4jsf is part of RichFaces.

Comment: Thank you! I am using IceFaces ACE Component now, I find that <ace:comboBox> component allows users to select a value from a number of given options, while also allowing them to enter a custom value in the text field. Thank you!

Comment: You tagged the question with `[ajax4jsf]` which is quite confusing. Do you read the tag descriptions just in case you really understand what the term stands for? Of was you just incorrectly assuming that "ajax4jsf" is something specific to ICEfaces or even standard JSF itself? What exactly do you have in mind when you think about "ajax4jsf"?

Answer (score 0):

just use `ace:comboBox`. this component allows users to manually enter data